# How to call VOICECLOUD API using PHP

Tags: php, api, voice

I want to transcribe (Voice to Text) using [VoiceCloud API](http://v1.voicecloud.com/api.php).
The API documentation is lacking the examples for it.

I want to send the (mp3,wav) file using VoiceCloud API.
How to send/call the API using PHP.
The API provide me only the bellow single line of code to call the API:

```
http/:voicecloudURL/api?action=sendfile&username=youruserid&devkey=abc123&idtype=username&fileurl=http:/yourserver/file.mp3
```

Should I use CURL for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use CURL for it?

That would be the best bet. Make a request to that URL and catch the response from it. Read from their **`API`** docs that they will return an **`XML response`** [consists of `transactionuid`]. Make use of **`SimpleXMLElement`** to grab the `transactionuid` as you can thus proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

You may use just fopen function if opening url is allow in php.ini. Or using curl_init and other cURL functions.